# Implementar troca de mensagens entre aplicações

Tags: android

Tenho um app o qual tem duas versões, versão usuário e versão prestador de serviço, onde nele há uma troca de mensagens, gostaria de saber quais opções tenho para implementar essa troca de mensagens, hoje estou realizando sempre Queries perguntando ao servidor se tem algo novo, mas acredito que não seja uma solução boa, porque ele sempre faz muitas requisições ao servidor, visto que essas queries rodam a cada segundo.
Estou utilizando o Parse.com o qual provê o serviço de Push que é baseado no GCM da google, porém as mensagens nem sempre chegam em 'tempo real' e também há alteração na ordem das mensagens.

Comment: Uma opção interessante é usar um _Backend as a Service_ focado em tempo de resposta como o FireBase e fazer o seu aplicativo escutar diretamente as mudanças nos dados relevantes em vez de receber pelo GCM.

Comment: @mateus-carvalho veja se esse post te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119649/que-estrat%C3%A9gia-usar-para-criar-site-que-manda-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-aplicativo-androi/119793#119793

Answer (score 1):

Na minha humilde opinião, já que você está começando, o interessante seria você fazer mais algumas pesquisas para poder oferecer esse tipo de serviço ao público, que acredito eu que futuramente seja sua pretensão. Esse negócio de "tempo-real", "mensagem instantânea", etc; é um pouco mais complexo. Imagine o Whatsapp, quanto tempo demorou para oferecer o serviço de chamada, aquele que você faz ligação sem ter que pagar, apenas através da internet. Pois bem, vemos que até hoje não lançaram vídeo chamada, por ser basicamente por ser no mínimo complexo demais. bla bla bla...

Mas então, gostaria de apresentar a você dois o **Quickblox** e o **Q-municate**, pai e filho, unidos para facilitar a vida de muita gente de muitos diferentes lugares. Eles são projetos de um aplicativo de bate-papo, transferência de arquivos, notificações; com tudo já implementado e de código aberto. Com eles você vai encontrar a documentação da API completa para o API REST, e o SDK Quickblox para iOS, Android, eo SDK JavaScript. Além também um conjunto de tutoriais e amostras de código.

## [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/)

Uma empresa desenvolvimento de aplicativos e consultoria e de soluções cliente-servidor que permite que você construa aplicações mais poderosas e envolventes com mais facilidade. O QuickBlox possui suas próprias instâncias **Amazon** no qual disponibiliza para pequenos desenvolvedores de aplicações *mobile* ou *web*, no intuito de facilitar no desenvolvimento.

## [Q-municate](http://q-municate.com/)

O Q-municate, o filho, trata-se de uma ferramenta que faz toda integração para comunicação entre suas aplicações com diferentes plataformas.

> Q-municate é um projeto de um aplicativo de bate-papo com uma vasta
>   gama de funcionalidades de comunicação incluído (tais como mensagens,
>   transferência de arquivos, as notificações push, chamadas de áudio/vídeo).

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android

### Screnshots

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Detalhes

- [QuickBlox/q-municate-android](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android)
- [QuickBlox](http://QuickBlox)

#### Boa Sorte!!! Boa leitura! Vale a pena, acredite!