# Que estratégia usar para criar site que manda informações para aplicativo Android?

Tags: android

Vou fazer um aplicativo Android para uma loja. Minha ideia é criar um site para que dono da loja possa mandar as informações de preço e imagens para serem exibidos nesse aplicativo.

Como fazer isso? Seria Web Service?

Comment: O que faz a comunicação entre um Apk (aplicativo) e um sistema (Banco de Dados). é  um web services ou o mais atual o Web Api.

Comment: Recomendo um API REST mandando os dados via Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia desenvolver um aplicativo utilizando um web service, e para isso bocê pode utilizar tecnologias como SQLite, KSOAP e entre outras.

Algumas tecnologias:

1 – KSOAP2

http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android

2 – SQLite

http://www.sqlite.org

3 – Realm

https://realm.io

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito Bom o conteúdo....me ajudou muito estava com duvida nessa parte de web service e hospedagem....Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Sim, a ideia seria fazer um webservice pra esse processo. Posso te recomendar duas coisas, se você for fazer o Webservice em java, gerando JSON, pode utilizar o jersey, que é muito simples, aqui um tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Com relação ao consumo no android, te recomendo mais ainda que utilize o retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/, o maior cuidado que você teria que ter seria com as imagens, o que você pode fazer é o upload para uma pasta do servidor(ao invés de persistir no banco), e gravar o link onde está hospedado a imagem no banco, no android pega esse link e baixa a imagem. acho que isso já te ajuda.

Comment: Geferson, Interessante...esse Retrofit, nunca ouvi falar dela... é uma IDE ? entrei no site apareceu os código pronto, copio esse código a onde ? descupa sobre essa pergunta tosca... mas é minha duvida

Comment: O Retrofit é um framework pra android para comunicação com Webservices Restful. você implementa O Webservice com o jersey que comentei acima, esse vai te fornecer os dados, e com o retrofit no android você "consome" essas informações, posso te recomendar esse vídeo, explicando como utilizar o retrofit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMt4d1dp07Q, qualquer coisa poste aí que te ajudamos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com web service sim, seria no formato API REST ao meu ver, no qual você consome e fornece dados a mesma base de dados, tudo no formato JSON. Você pode usar desde php para fazer isso, como outras tecnologias, como node.js, c# (.net) com web api entre outras... vai da sua necessidade.

Comment: Denner Evaldt Machado, seria básico mesmo. uma tela de login e outra tela para o dono da loja armazenar as informações. só essas duas tela

Comment: Faça uma análise da linguagem que você é mais familiarizado e de uma estudada sobre esse formato de api, para poder consumir e fornecer dados do mesmo local.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelo Feed back....vou estudar sobre isso sim!